# programatically add attachment in custom list in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i have registered ItemAttachmentAdded in my custom list.can anyone send me some code how can i add attachment in custom list.

Comment: Post your code and then ask a question about the one or two lines where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google told me how to do it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spattachmentcollection.add.aspx

```
byte[] fileData = GetFileData();
SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["My List"].Items[0].Attachments.Add("filename", fileData)
```